# What is difference between Azure AD Module and MS Online module

Tags: powershell, azure, module

I am trying to understand difference between two modules, Azure AD and MS Online modules. Currently on my windows 10 machine I can use get-azureaccount cmdlet that returns my current Azure account. And there is bunch of cmdlets that I can use right now. Then why I need MS Online module.

Please help me to understand the purpose of these two modules.

Comment: MS online module is required to work with Office 365.

Answer (score 2):

Get-AzureAccount / Get-AzureRMAccount is a part of the "Azure" module.

When working with Azure AD (Active directory commands; not a part of the built-in modules) in Azure you will need the MSOnline module - which also happens to be the same module as for working with Office365. Usually MSOnline is referred to as the Azure Active Directory module for Windows Powershell.

Eg. if you install the Azure Active Directory module from example here: [Microsoft - Active Directory Module for Windows Powershell 64-bit](http://wordpress.redirectingat.com/?id=725X1342&site=expertslab.wordpress.com&xs=1&isjs=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgo.microsoft.com%2Ffwlink%2Fp%2F%3Flinkid%3D236297&xguid=4b609e9d63de237b29ab1ccfad372030&xuuid=d5c71cbe60bcc1f74efb3d5abc18355a&xsessid=292391785070d77880f0b804fdd7d4f9&xcreo=0&xed=0&sref=https%3A%2F%2Fexpertslab.wordpress.com%2F2015%2F07%2F13%2Finstall-windows-azure-active-directory-module-for-windows-powershell%2F&pref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.fi%2F&xtz=-120&abp=1) - you will get the MSOnline module installed on your machine. You can actually inspect / unpack the msi installer and you will see that the package here is Microsoft.Online.Administration.MSOnline.psd1

In order to work with Azure AD from Powershell, you'll then need to import this module (which contains a set of functions to work with Azure AD).

To list commands within this module after installing the module you can do the following:

```
Get-Command -Module MSOnline
```

Hope this clears the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Connect-Azure: allows user to manage Active Directory objects only, [where directory is hosted in Azure].

Connect-Msoline: apart from managing Active Directory allows more administrative tasks such as Domain management, configure single sign-on etc.

Hope this clarifies your doubt.
Reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-msonlinev1?view=azureadps-1.0

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's a matter of selecting the best tool for the job. And the way to select the tool is based on

1. What you're going to do with it &
2. what does the tool do

If we take a look at the properties offered by get-msoluser

```
(get-msoluser)[0] | gm -MemberType Properties
```

we get a slightly different set than we do when we query get-azureaduser with

```
(get-azureaduser)[0] | gm -MemberType Properties
```

and the same can be said when we review the methods available to the objects:

```
 (get-azureaduser)[0] | gm -MemberType Method
```

or

```
 (get-msoluser)[0] | gm -MemberType Method
```

Now, since the general idea is to get things done quickly and simply. It then becomes clear to use the one that directly supports what you intend to achieve. And if they both cover the job then I would base my decision of which additional cmdlets in the module support the task I want to achieve without needing to load a whole stack of modules.

So I hope this helps find the right tool for the job.
Have fun,

Porky